# Swift: Is there a way to make an SKAction sequence that uses more than one object?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, sequence, skaction

I have a sequence that spawns enemies and then moves them across the screen, it essentially reads

```
moveAndRemoveEnemy = SKAction.sequence([moveEnemy, removeEnemy]) 
enemy.runAction(moveAndRemoveEnemy)
```

The problem is I want to add another action to the sequence which updates the score after the enemy is removed. I have tried making a separate method that increases the score, calling it as an SKAction.runBlock() and inserting it into the sequence, as in

```
let updateScore = SKAction.runBlock { self.increaseScore() }
moveAndRemoveEnemy = SKAction.sequence([moveEnemy, removeEnemy, updateScore])
enemy.runAction(moveAndRemoveEnemy)
```

but this doesn't work. I think the reason it doesn't work is because the method needs to be called using "self", as in

```
self.runAction(increaseScore)
```

I have tried putting the enemy spawning and moving into a separate method, and then using

```
self.runAction(moveAndRemoveEnemy)
```

but this causes the problem to reverse itself, so that the updateScore works, but the enemies don't spawn. Unfortunately I have tried other ways of increasing the score, and they do work for a period of time, but based on how my game is set up they eventually break down as the levels get harder. Does anyone know any ways around this? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look into SKNode's [runAction:completion:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKNode/runAction:completion:) method. This will call `completion()` after the action has been completed.

Or, in Swift: `runAction(_ action: SKAction!, completion block: (() -> Void)!)`.

Comment: This worked! I had never used the runAction:completion method before, thanks for showing me. I have a feeling this is going to help me in many areas of my code. Cheers.

Comment: If this answered your question, please mark it as the accepted answer to resolve the question.

Answer (score 2):

For those that are interested, the final solution reads:

```
enemy.runAction(moveAndRemoveEnemy, completion: {self.runAction(updateScore)})
```

Comment: BTW, you can use a trailing closure to accomplish the same: `enemy.runAction(moveAndRemoveEnemy) {self.runAction(updateScore)}`

Answer (score 1):

If `removeEnemy` removes `enemy` from the scene, the action will stop because the node that is executing the action *must* be in the scene to continue running the action. If you change the order of the sequence to `[moveEnemy, updateScore, removeEnemy]`, `updateScore` will be called.

Comment: I never knew the node still had to be in the scene, thanks! Unfortunately changing the sequence that way won't work for me because it updates the score at the wrong time, e.g. when the enemy is spawned and not removed.

Comment: Does this mean the better order for the trailing closure would be: `enemy.runAction(moveAndUpdateScore) {self.runAction(removeEnemy)}`

Comment: @Confused it depends what you're trying to accomplish. My point is that removing the node will automatically stop the action and all other actions in the sequence will not execute.